# Unable to resolve multiple build failures error

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

I tried to add the support fragments and the issue started from there. Support libraries are not supported the build version. Previously the build version was 28 and the support libraries version was 27.1.1. This was working well.

I tried to update the version to 28 and then support libraries to 28.0.0.
But its giving me error. After getting the multiple errors now I am at manifest merger error.

I tried to use androidx as suggested on stackoverflow for the support libraries. But it is very long and tiresome process to import the amother library in each class of a project. I am not willing to do that.

Is there any other way to solve this?

app : Gradle file

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.creditone.admin.OnBoarding"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 61
        versionName "1.11"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        quiet true
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation project(':digio-esign2')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.7'
    // compile 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+@aar'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //   compile files('libs/svg-android.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.1.1'
    implementation project(path: ':trustscore')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project: gradle file

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'
            name 'Google'}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Manifest File :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.creditone.admin.OnBoarding">

    <!--MANDATORY-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <!--RECOMMENDED-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!--OPTIONAL-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.cv.trustscore.TrustScoreApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/petrolpump"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace='android:appComponentFactory'
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Login.Login"
            android:label="@string/login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.MainDriver"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.Alert"
            android:label="@string/alert"
            android:parentActivityName=".ExistingUser.Activities.MainDriver"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.ForgotPassword"
            android:label="@string/forgot_pass"
            android:parentActivityName=".ExistingUser.Activities.MainDriver"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.MyCard"
            android:label="@string/myAccount"
            android:parentActivityName=".ExistingUser.Activities.MainDriver"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.RegisterFleetUser"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/register"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.PetrolPump"
            android:label="@string/petrolPump"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.PetrolPumpDetailsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ExistingUser.Activities.MainDriver"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBPLMU1KtW833-GTWnTGxt0SQFqbOFRXLM" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.LimitManagement"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/limitsMgmt"
            android:parentActivityName=".ExistingUser.Activities.MainDriver"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.RegisterDriver"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/register"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.CardClick"
            android:label="@string/cardUsage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.Statmnt"
            android:label="@string/statement"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.StatmntDriver"
            android:label="@string/statement"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/petrolpump" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="noti" />

        <receiver android:name=".Helper.SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".Service.SmsDumpReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.ReConfirmLoginUserActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="93ba6305e7b15e13e63c754ddad69250bd7f86a1" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingUser.Activities.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BasicStartUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_basic_start_up"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NewUser.Activities.ENachOptionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NewUser.Activities.ENachFormActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NewUser.Activities.EULAActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_eula">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now getting this error:

```
    org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:358)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:219)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:540)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:173)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 34 more
```

Manifest merger shows some error which takes me to manifest file but unable to identify the error.

[image]

[image]

[image]
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: see Manifest merger

Comment: check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794164/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-see-logs-when-updating-firebase-and) answers. you may get some hint.

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki I tried to check in manifest merger but unable to get the error. Please check the edited question.

Comment: Add below lines to `gradle.properties file

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true` and remove tools:replace

Comment: android.useAndroidX=true this makes me to change all imported support libraries in all classes. I don not wish to do so. @Ashvinsolanki

Comment: `android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"` add this in menifiest

Comment: its not helping. I am getting error. Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from AndroidManifest.xml:40:9-82
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:32:5-357:19 to override.
@Ashvinsolanki

Answer (score 1):

I have migrated to androidx which is recommended for support libraries after 28.0.0 and comiple version 28.

Following gives the description of androidx

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/

I checked this video to avoid hassel of changing the import libraries manually.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FZ_eUIsLTg

Hope this helps for the developers who will be facing this issue. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Steps to solve it:

- Clean build
- Invalidate caches
- run `gradlew assembleDebug` this will show you where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try out with following options

1. Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment->Instant Run->Uncheck Enable Instant Run
2. Update dependencies versions to comply with target SDK version. If you notice any version missmatches try with second option first and if it not resolved moved to first option.